# SQL Math in SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have create a query which solves this problem.

I have a DB with the structure like this

```
+-----+---------------------+---------+---------+
| id  | since               | idUsers | km      |
+-----+---------------------+---------+---------+
| 124 | 2005-07-18 15:00:00 |       1 | 25798.0 |
| 127 | 2005-07-19 18:00:00 |       3 | 25891.7 |
| 128 | 2005-07-20 00:00:00 |       3 | 25970.2 |
| 129 | 2005-07-18 12:00:00 |       3 | 25795.0 |
| 136 | 2005-07-19 15:00:00 |       1 | 25852.0 |
| 137 | 2005-07-23 12:00:00 |       1 | 26143.6 |
| 139 | 2005-08-07 00:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 140 | 2005-08-21 00:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 146 | 2005-07-27 15:00:00 |       2 | 26164.0 |
| 147 | 2005-07-28 15:00:00 |       2 | 26178.9 |
| 151 | 2005-08-17 13:00:00 |       1 | 26245.0 |
| 149 | 2005-08-08 18:00:00 |       1 | 26204.9 |
| 150 | 2005-08-10 15:00:00 |       1 | 26221.4 |
| 155 | 2005-08-27 19:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 154 | 2005-08-29 09:00:00 |       2 | 26438.3 |
| 156 | 2005-08-28 00:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 157 | 2005-08-29 14:00:00 |       3 | 26468.3 |
| 158 | 2005-09-07 15:00:00 |       2 | 26504.2 |
| 159 | 2005-09-05 13:00:00 |       1 | 26478.5 |
| 160 | 2005-09-02 13:00:00 |       1 | 26473.8 |
| 161 | 2005-09-25 12:00:00 |       3 | 26550.4 |
| 162 | 2006-04-02 13:00:00 |       3 | 26599.0 |
| 163 | 2006-04-14 18:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 164 | 2006-04-15 00:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 169 | 2006-04-16 00:00:00 |       1 | 26703.3 |
| 166 | 2006-04-29 12:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 168 | 2006-04-30 00:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 170 | 2006-04-16 08:00:00 |       3 | 26709.0 |
| 175 | 2006-05-27 00:00:00 |       3 |    NULL |
| 176 | 2006-05-28 00:00:00 |       3 | 27072.0 |
| 177 | 2006-05-26 18:00:00 |       3 |    NULL |
| 178 | 2006-04-18 15:00:00 |       2 | 26751.0 |
| 179 | 2006-04-16 17:00:00 |       2 | 26726.0 |
| 181 | 2006-04-23 07:00:00 |       3 | 26775.0 |
| 182 | 2006-05-01 00:00:00 |       1 | 26932.4 |
| 183 | 2006-04-30 18:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 184 | 2006-05-11 17:00:00 |       2 | 26988.0 |
| 186 | 2006-06-12 12:00:00 |       2 | 27092.0 |
| 187 | 2006-06-11 19:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 188 | 2006-06-12 00:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 189 | 2006-06-15 17:00:00 |       2 | 27134.0 |
| 191 | 2006-07-01 11:00:00 |       3 | 27199.0 |
| 192 | 2006-06-23 16:00:00 |       3 | 27162.0 |
| 193 | 2006-07-09 15:00:00 |       2 | 27211.0 |
| 194 | 2006-06-30 18:00:00 |       1 | 27183.0 |
| 195 | 2006-07-26 11:00:00 |       2 |    NULL |
| 196 | 2006-08-15 14:00:00 |       2 | 27351.0 |
| 197 | 2006-08-05 16:00:00 |       3 | 27338.0 |
| 198 | 2006-08-06 16:00:00 |       3 | 27341.0 |
| 199 | 2006-09-05 18:00:00 |       3 |    NULL |
| 201 | 2006-09-06 00:00:00 |       3 | 27506.0 |
| 202 | 2006-09-16 13:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 203 | 2006-09-17 00:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 204 | 2006-09-18 00:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 205 | 2006-09-19 00:00:00 |       1 | 27568.6 |
| 206 | 2006-10-10 18:00:00 |       1 | 27569.4 |
| 207 | 2006-10-30 15:00:00 |       1 | 27581.5 |
| 209 | 2006-12-29 18:00:00 |       2 |    NULL |
| 216 | 2007-04-01 08:00:00 |       1 | 27725.0 |
| 227 | 2007-04-26 00:00:00 |       2 |    NULL |
| 214 | 2007-03-29 09:00:00 |       1 | 27675.5 |
| 215 | 2007-03-31 10:00:00 |       1 | 27689.2 |
| 225 | 2007-04-15 08:00:00 |       1 | 27880.3 |
| 224 | 2007-04-14 19:00:00 |       1 | 27800.0 |
| 223 | 2007-04-14 12:00:00 |       1 | 27775.0 |
| 228 | 2007-04-26 23:00:00 |       2 |    NULL |
| 229 | 2007-04-27 00:00:00 |       2 | 28000.4 |
| 230 | 2007-04-28 00:00:00 |       2 |    NULL |
| 231 | 2007-04-25 12:00:00 |       2 |    NULL |
| 232 | 2007-04-20 18:00:00 |       1 | 27906.3 |
| 233 | 2007-04-22 15:00:00 |       1 | 27928.6 |
| 234 | 2007-04-21 17:00:00 |       1 | 27915.2 |
| 236 | 2007-04-23 19:00:00 |       1 | 28068.0 |
| 237 | 2007-05-01 07:00:00 |       3 | 28103.0 |
| 238 | 2007-04-28 18:00:00 |       1 | 28030.3 |
| 239 | 2007-05-20 11:00:00 |       1 | 28174.2 |
| 240 | 2007-05-20 15:00:00 |       2 | 28181.0 |
| 241 | 2007-05-23 16:00:00 |       2 | 28198.0 |
| 242 | 2007-06-03 16:00:00 |       2 | 28238.0 |
| 243 | 2007-06-10 09:00:00 |       3 |    NULL |
| 244 | 2007-07-01 12:00:00 |       2 | 28291.0 |
| 245 | 2007-07-07 15:00:00 |       2 | 28343.0 |
| 246 | 2007-07-30 15:00:00 |       1 | 28354.8 |
| 247 | 2007-07-31 12:00:00 |       1 | 28476.9 |
| 248 | 2007-08-01 15:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 249 | 2007-08-04 11:00:00 |       3 |    NULL |
| 250 | 2007-08-05 00:00:00 |       3 |    NULL |
| 251 | 2007-08-05 10:00:00 |       3 |    NULL |
| 252 | 2007-08-06 00:00:00 |       3 | 28708.0 |
| 253 | 2007-08-09 17:00:00 |       1 | 28729.9 |
| 254 | 2007-08-24 19:00:00 |       2 | 28806.0 |
| 255 | 2007-09-01 10:00:00 |       2 | 28812.0 |
| 256 | 2007-09-16 13:00:00 |       3 | 28842.0 |
| 257 | 2007-10-16 02:00:00 |       2 |    NULL |
| 258 | 2008-06-19 12:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 259 | 2008-06-20 00:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 260 | 2008-06-21 00:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 261 | 2008-06-22 00:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 262 | 2008-06-23 00:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 263 | 2008-06-24 00:00:00 |       1 | 28986.7 |
| 264 | 2008-06-26 18:00:00 |       2 | 28997.0 |
| 265 | 2008-06-29 13:00:00 |       2 | 28998.0 |
| 266 | 2008-06-29 18:00:00 |       3 | 29012.0 |
| 267 | 2008-07-08 16:00:00 |       2 | 29019.0 |
| 268 | 2008-07-28 18:00:00 |       2 | 29082.0 |
| 269 | 2008-08-10 15:00:00 |       2 | 29192.0 |
| 270 | 2008-08-21 17:00:00 |       2 |    NULL |
| 271 | 2008-08-24 13:00:00 |       2 | 29281.0 |
| 272 | 2008-08-27 21:00:00 |       3 |    NULL |
| 273 | 2008-08-28 00:00:00 |       3 |    NULL |
| 274 | 2008-08-29 00:00:00 |       3 |    NULL |
| 275 | 2008-08-30 00:00:00 |       3 | 29343.0 |
| 276 | 2008-08-30 18:00:00 |       2 | 29352.0 |
| 277 | 2008-09-05 17:00:00 |       2 | 29385.0 |
| 279 | 2008-10-10 14:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 280 | 2008-10-11 00:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 281 | 2008-10-12 00:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 282 | 2008-10-13 00:00:00 |       1 | 29459.0 |
| 283 | 2009-04-05 10:00:00 |       2 | 29460.0 |
| 286 | 2009-04-19 10:00:00 |       3 | 29471.0 |
| 285 | 2009-05-02 00:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 287 | 2009-04-22 15:00:00 |       2 | 29486.0 |
| 288 | 2009-05-01 10:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 290 | 2009-05-20 15:00:00 |       3 |    NULL |
| 289 | 2009-05-03 00:00:00 |       1 | 29668.6 |
| 291 | 2009-05-21 00:00:00 |       3 |    NULL |
| 292 | 2009-05-22 00:00:00 |       3 |    NULL |
| 293 | 2009-05-23 00:00:00 |       3 |    NULL |
| 294 | 2009-05-22 09:00:00 |       3 |    NULL |
| 295 | 2009-05-24 00:00:00 |       3 | 29820.0 |
| 296 | 2009-05-31 15:00:00 |       2 | 29830.0 |
| 297 | 2009-06-07 16:00:00 |       1 | 29850.3 |
| 298 | 2009-07-05 00:00:00 |       1 |     0.0 |
| 299 | 2009-06-28 12:00:00 |       2 | 29895.0 |
| 300 | 2009-07-04 17:00:00 |       2 | 29977.0 |
| 301 | 2009-06-29 16:00:00 |       2 | 29935.0 |
| 302 | 2009-07-11 19:00:00 |       2 | 29991.0 |
| 303 | 2009-07-26 17:00:00 |       2 | 29993.0 |
| 304 | 2009-07-27 00:00:00 |       3 | 30138.0 |
| 305 | 2009-08-04 18:00:00 |       3 | 30200.0 |
| 306 | 2009-08-05 00:00:00 |       3 | 30205.0 |
| 307 | 2009-08-06 00:00:00 |       3 | 30219.0 |
| 308 | 2009-08-15 09:00:00 |       3 |    NULL |
| 309 | 2009-08-15 20:00:00 |       2 | 30357.0 |
| 310 | 2009-09-06 12:00:00 |       2 | 30408.0 |
| 311 | 2009-09-07 17:00:00 |       2 | 30453.0 |
| 312 | 2009-09-11 11:00:00 |       2 |     0.0 |
| 313 | 2009-10-25 08:00:00 |       1 | 30531.7 |
| 314 | 2009-10-01 19:00:00 |       1 |     0.0 |
| 317 | 2010-04-07 18:00:00 |       2 | 30571.0 |
| 316 | 2010-03-31 10:00:00 |       1 |     0.0 |
| 318 | 2010-04-18 12:00:00 |       2 | 30640.0 |
| 319 | 2010-04-29 13:00:00 |       1 | 30665.5 |
| 320 | 2010-05-21 16:00:00 |       3 |    NULL |
| 321 | 2010-05-22 00:00:00 |       3 | 30752.6 |
| 322 | 2010-05-26 19:00:00 |       1 | 30762.4 |
| 323 | 2010-05-29 18:00:00 |       1 | 30810.8 |
| 344 | 2010-07-19 16:00:00 |       1 | 31062.7 |
| 348 | 2010-08-22 13:00:00 |       2 |    NULL |
| 347 | 2010-08-08 09:00:00 |       2 | 31567.0 |
| 346 | 2010-07-25 15:00:00 |       1 | 31485.5 |
| 345 | 2010-07-20 11:00:00 |       1 |     0.0 |
| 343 | 2010-07-21 00:00:00 |       1 | 31382.5 |
| 334 | 2010-06-07 14:00:00 |       2 | 30837.0 |
| 335 | 2010-06-24 18:00:00 |       2 | 30853.0 |
| 336 | 2010-07-01 15:00:00 |       2 |    NULL |
| 337 | 2010-07-03 07:00:00 |       2 | 30948.0 |
| 338 | 2010-07-13 12:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 339 | 2010-07-13 19:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 340 | 2010-07-12 16:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 341 | 2010-07-11 21:00:00 |       1 |    NULL |
| 349 | 2010-08-22 13:00:00 |       2 | 31682.0 |
| 350 | 2010-09-05 06:00:00 |       2 | 31724.0 |
| 351 | 2010-09-19 14:00:00 |       1 | 31772.4 |
+-----+---------------------+---------+---------+
```

Now i have to find out which user drove how many km..
it could be easy with

```
Select r.idUsers, SUM(r.km) AS KM_TOTAL FROM Reservations r GROUP BY r.idUsers
```

but the problem is the value in the km field is the value of the car right now, so basically i have to find out the difference between the id from the next row and the current row (id127.km - id124.km)
but i just started programming and i dont know how to solve this

The end results need be shown like this:

```
idUsers | TOTAL_KM
1       | (Total value of his km)
2       | (Total value of his km)
3       | (Total value of his km)
```

I hope you can help me

EDIT:

```
SELECT tt.iduser,sum(tt.next_km - tt.km) as TOTAL_KM
FROM (
SELECT t.iduser,t.km,
       (SELECT s.km FROM Reservations s
        WHERE s.since > t.since
        ORDER BY s.since
        LIMIT 1) as next_km
FROM Reservations t) tt
WHERE tt.next_km is not null
GROUP BY tt.iduser
```

Gives the output

```
idusers | TOTAL_KM
1 | 62141.9 
2 | -59284.9 
3 | 596.9
```

Comment: Remove lots of tags. Put one back, the one for the dbms you're using.

Comment: Edit the question and add the expected result.

Comment: How about finding the min and max kms for each driver and printing their difference?

Comment: Please edit your title with some actual problem you have, not just `schoolwork`

Comment: Is `km` the odometer reading from when the user got the car, or when they returned it? You seem to have two timestamps, for when the car was checked out and in, why don't you also have two odometer readings?

Comment: it should be when they got the car and i didnt make the DB, that was my teacher and we can't change it unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a correlated query to fetch the next `KM` , and them sum the difference between them for each user :

```
SELECT tt.iduser,sum(tt.next_km - tt.km) as TOTAL_KM
FROM (
    SELECT t.iduser,t.km,
           (SELECT s.km FROM Reservations s
            WHERE s.since > t.since
            ORDER BY s.since
            LIMIT 1) as next_km
    FROM Reservations t) tt
WHERE tt.next_km is not null
  AND tt.km is not null
GROUP BY tt.iduser
```

You didn't tag your RDBMS, if its SQL-Server use to `TOP 1` , if its MySQL use the `LIMIT 1` , if its something else, then tell me and I'll adjust it.

Comment: yeah sorry i forgot about that, it's MySQL
so i removed <TOP 1>  and removed the <> from LIMIT 1 but now it says the table does not exist

Comment: Than I updated the answer to the use of `LIMIT` , should work now. @Damon

Comment: okay i got it work with 
    SELECT tt.idusers,sum(tt.next_km - tt.km) as TOTAL_KM
FROM (
    SELECT t.idusers,t.km,
           (SELECT s.km FROM Reservations s
            WHERE s.since > t.since
            ORDER BY s.since
            LIMIT 1) as next_km
    FROM Reservations t) tt
GROUP BY tt.idusers


but i get the values 


`idusers | TOTAL_KM
1 | 62141.9 
2 | -59284.9
3 | 596.9`

Comment: still the same output:/

Comment: That's weird, can you edit the question with the output you get?  @damon

Comment: Can you please say the order of the reservations? Which one is first and which one is last? I don't understanx the order @damon

Comment: yeah i just noticed the timestamp isn't in the correct order.. sorry about that
the we have to order it by `since`

Comment: But can you tell me the order? is it -> `ID-> 129,124,136,127,128` ? @Damon

Comment: exactly, sorry my english is not the best:/

Comment: @Damon Is `SINCE` column is date? or string ?

Comment: since and till are both datetime

Comment: Then this query should work! Maybe you are not looking at the data correctly? Anyway edit and give an example of input , and the out put of **that** input , I see userid 2 in your result and you didn't give an input for that user. @Damon

Comment: yeah because the table has about 25 rows and i didnt want to put everything into the question @sagi

Comment: @Damon But without all the data I won't be able to understand why this is happening, I told you, this should work

Comment: sorry, i put in al the rows i have in that table

Comment: What are all this null values?? @Damon What should I do with them?

Comment: So what I am suppose to do with them? Ignore this rows? This will mess up the ranges

Comment: @Damon Try the query now and tell me if it seems correct / closer to the solution

Comment: yeah probably ignore them..

still the same output as the query before

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.iduser,max(r.km)-min(r.km) as TOTAL_KM
FROM Reservations r
WHERE r.km is not null
GROUP BY r.iduser
```